# Training SVC from scikit-learn shows that using -h 0 may be faster?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, multiclass-classification

I am training an SVC model on a large dataset, and since I have set `verbose=True`, it is showing a  `Warning: using -h 0 may be faster`.

I have two questions here:

- what is this warning and how we can set any option of libsvm as it has mentioned in the warning?
- Does the size of cache in `sklearn.svm.SVC` parameter setting can affect the speed of training? I have set it as `cache_size=2000` .

Your expert view is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-h` parameter controls shrinking: whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)

You can set it in the SVC constructor using `shrinking` argument. Shrinking is a heuristics to speed up the optimization problem.

Check [Original Paper](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) and 
[Similar Quesiton on shrinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500261/libsvm-shrinking-heuristics)

Caching is technique for reducing the computational time of the decomposition method which is part of the training. This size is controlled via `cache_size` parameter.

I higlhy recommend reading the original libsm paper, especially section 5.